# Batch File to archive files based on their name

Tags: batch-file

I have text files that I need to archive daily and would like to automate it.
There are about 100 User Folders and each User folder has 20 subfolders.

```
Ex User Folder structure:
    D:\Logs\John Hayse\01
    D:\Logs\John Hayse\02
    D:\Logs\John Hayse\03
    etc... up to D:\Logs\John Hayse\20

Ex filenames:
    John.Hayes.T01.Daily.Log.txt
    John.Hayes.T02.Daily.Log.txt
    John.Hayes.T04.Tasks.To.Complete.txt
    Billy.Gavin.T02.Daily.Logs.txt
```

I started righting a batch file that does hundreds of if exist statements like this:

```
if exist D:\John.Hayes.T01* move D:\John.Hayes.T01* D:\Logs\John Hayse\01"
if exist D:\John.Hayes.T02* move D:\John.Hayes.T02* D:\Logs\John Hayse\02"
```

If I create a separate text file containing all the Users folders:

```
dir "D\Logs" /b /a:d >D:\UserFolderList.txt
```

How would I use that to create the if exist statement once and loop through all of the Users files and place them in the proper User folder and in their corresponding subfolder ##?

```
Ex.
D:\John.Hayes.T02.Daily.Log.txt archive to D:\Logs\John Hayes\02
```

The users files always start with their FirstName.LastName.T## but the User's folder has a space instead of a '.' in between their First and Last name.

Comment: If you want a packaged batch file then describe the actual task - source folders, files, target folder tree, if it's on a network, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*" '
  ) DO FOR %%n IN (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a.%%b.t%%n.*" (
   MD  "%destdir%\%%a %%b\%%n\"
   MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a.%%b.t%%n.*" "%destdir%\%%a %%b\%%n\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should execute the task you describe - you'd need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit.

The destination directory is created if it does not already exist. Append `2>nul` to the `MD` line to suppress the `already exists` message if desired.

Note that there is an obvious flaw in your scheme. You are not apparently catering for the possibility that the destination file already exists.